# Storm supervisor cat't connect the zk

Tags: apache-storm

the error msg in supervisor.log: Storm supervisor cat't create stormClusterState
at the same time，It is empty in the /storm/supervisor directory of zk.The nimbus process can be started but the supervisor cannot start.why?

the error msg in supervisor.log:
ava.lang.Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperExceptionsConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /stom
at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.handleUncaughtException(Utils.java:663)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.handleUncaughtException(Utils.java:667)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.lambda$createDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler$2(Utils.java:1047)[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$$Lambda$17/00000000F826AC00.uncaughtException(UnknownSource)[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at java. lang. ThreadGroup.uncaughtException (ThreadGroup.java:B68) [7:1.8.0_2421
at java.lang. ThreadGroup.uncaughtException (ThreadGroup. java: 866) [?:1.8.0 242j
at java.lang.Thread.uncaughtException(Thread.java: 1335) [7:1.8.0 242]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException:KeeperErrorCode=ConnectionLossfor/storm
at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.wrapInRuntime(Utils.java:493)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ClientZookeeper.existsNode(ClientZookeeper.java:147)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ClientZookeeper.mkdirsImpl(ClientZookeeper.java:288)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ClientZookeeper.mkdirs(ClientZookeeper.java:70)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.cluster.ZKStateStorage.(ZKStateStorage.java:65)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.cluster.ZKStateStorageFactory.mkStore(ZKStateStorageFactory.java:30)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.01
at org.apache.storm.cluster.ClusterUtils.mkStateStorageImpl(ClusterUtils.java:318)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.01
at org.apache.storm.cluster.ClusterUtils.mkStormClusterStateImpl(ClusterUtils.java:301)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.cluster.ClusterUtils.mkStormClusterState(ClusterUtils.java:286)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor. Supervisor.(Supervisor.java: 160) ~[storm-server-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Supervisor.(Supervisor.java:127)~[storm-server-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Supervisor.main(Supervisor.java:200)~[storm-server-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
caused by: org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /storm
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)~[storm-shaded-deps-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)~[storm-shaded-deps-2.3.0.jar:2.3.01
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1l11)~[storm-shaded-deps-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$3.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:268)~[storm-shaded-deps-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$3.call(ExistsBuj.derImpl.java:257)~[storm-shaded-deps-2.3.0.jar:2.3.01
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.connection.StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.callkäthRetry(StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.java:64)-[storm-shaded-deps
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:100)~[storm-shaded-deps-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForegroundStandard(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:254)~[storm-shaded-deps-2.3.0.jar:2.3
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:247)~[storm-shaded-deps-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:206)~[storm-shaded-deps-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:35)~[storm-shaded-deps-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ClientZookeeper.existsNode(ClientZookeeper.java:144)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ClientZookeeper.mkdirsImpl(ClientZookeeper.java:288)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ClientZookeeper.mkdirs(ClientZookeeper.java:70)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.cluster.ZKStateStorage.(ZKStateStorage.java:65)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.cluster.ZKStateStorageFactory.mkStore(ZKStateStorageFactory.java:30)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.cluster.ClusterUtils.mkStateStorageImpl(ClusterUtils.java:318)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.cluster.ClusterUtils.mkStormClusterStateImpl(ClusterUtils.java:301)~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.cluster.ClusterUtils.mkStormClusterState(ClusterUtils.java:286)-[storm-client-2.3.0.iar:2.3.01
at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Supervisor.(Supervisor.java:160)~[storm-server-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Supervisor.(Supervisor.java:127)~[storm-server-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon. supervisor.Supervisor.main (Supervisor.java:200) ~[storm-server-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: All error messages have been updated.

Comment: You are running Storm on cluster mode with multiple instances, right?

Comment: yeah, I try to start the storm cluster and the error occurs when starting the supervisor process.

Comment: zk is running smoothely?

Comment: Yes,zk looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

The /storm node already exists in the zk client, so the storm cluster cannot be connected when reconnecting to zk. You can log in to the zk client to delete the /storm node and then start the storm cluster related processes.